# Empty form sheet view. Ipad, Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift

I'm currently developing an app and I'm still only using the storyboard to develop the interface.

Everything is fine until I try to open a modal window, form sheet presentation. Where it shows me an empty view although I have some test labels and text fields present.

Image 1:
[view being shown no fields are present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBdrb.jpg)

If I open it some other way lets say a simple show it shows me the correct labels in there but not the layout I want.

Image 2:
[view being shown with the fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIL1C.jpg)

Is there a way around this?

Thank you for any help

edit: 
[view controller settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aa1l6g29qlthx5y/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-10-01%2011.31.52.png?dl=0)
 If I change presentation from form sheet to, for example, full screen, it works but the behaviour is incorrect.

Comment: What are you doing to show the view in each case?

Comment: What kind of auto layout constraints are on your fields?

Comment: @PhillipMills In image 1: Its a modal presentation, Image 2:  Its a "show detail" (As im using a splitview)

Comment: @Bek Im using Regular Width and Regular Height, as it is an iPad only app. I've edited the question with some aditional info.

Comment: Please show the code for the modal presentation.  I suspect you may be creating a controller without loading it from the storyboard.

Comment: I was using the storyboard alone with little to no code to try and minimize these errors. I have however managed to arrive to a solution although I don't know exactly why it happens like this. I played around with the Auto Layout and installed my view and the fields in all size classes (prior it was only Regular Width and Height) it now works as I want it to although, as mentioned I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced this same issue.

What happened was that I was designing the storyboard in with wR hR as opposed to wAny hAny as the size class. As such all views and constraints were installed in this size class, as opposed to all size classes. When a form sheet is presented modally its size class is not Regular/Regular, consequently the views and constraints are not installed. This also explains why things appear properly when a different presentation style is used.

To fix this issue, ensure that all views and constraints in your form sheet are installed universally, not just for a single size class. The screenshot demonstrates installation settings that will display in a form sheet.

[image: universal installation versus for specific size class]

Comment: in my case the constraints taken by the formsheet is "width compact and regular height" so its basically taking iphone constraints which is killing cause i need different constraint in iphone and formsheet  any help on this problem would be great

Comment: I'd sugest making different storyboards for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: As for this answer it gives a much more detailed explanation than my answer did so I'll mark it as correct answer and hope it helps anyone else

Comment: That helped me ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

After playing around with the size classes I installed my view and its fields on all size classes. Prior to that I was only using Regular width and height. After some tweaks on the position they were in I managed to get it to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was starting to pull my hair out after trying to track down the case of this issue for hours today.