# Present Modally / Form Sheet don't shows the content, always return empty / blank

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to show a View as a Form Sheet, but when it is displayed all the content disappears.

If I change the display option to Page Sheet the content is displayed again.

Could someone send the step by step to show it? All the answers I found were not so detailed ([Form Sheet content disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886372/form-sheet-content-disappearing) and [Empty form sheet view. Ipad, Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103816/empty-form-sheet-view-ipad-xcode-6))

I'm using Swift 2.0 and XCode 7.2.1

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thank you @user3847320 for the answer in the post [Empty form sheet view. Ipad, Xcode 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103816/empty-form-sheet-view-ipad-xcode-6?rq=1)

What I did (step by step):

Click on each object and constraint at Document Outline (at the left) and then check the two options "Installed" at Attributes Inspector (at the right).

[Objects at left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D2TD.png)

[Property at right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFqXr.png)